# Can I add a class to the <li>'s output by WordPress' wp_nav_menu() function?

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming

I'm using a grid layout, and all the links in my menu need the class `grid_1`, but WordPress automatically generates the classes `page_item page-item-#`. How can I add my class to the li? I'm aware that I could alternately add an entry under `.page_item` to my stylesheet, but I feel like that's more messy than it should be.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There's not a way but you can add a custom class to the ul and use that to target your li's.

```
$args = array(
'menu_class' => 'myclass'
);

wp_nav_menu($args);
```

Comment: Yeah. I just didn't want to have to duplicate the style of `.grid_1` in my stylesheet. Thanks for the answer though!